# Will voiding an order in Authorize.net automatically update status of order to closed/canceled in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, authorize.net

Curious if voiding an order in Authorize.net (before it's captured) will automatically update status of order to closed/canceled in Magento? I thought that was the default, but I just voided and the order is still "Processing" in Magento.

Will it move from processing after authorize.net batches orders at end of day or is there a setting I'm missing in either authorize.net or Magento?

Answer (score 2):

No it will not. There is no sending agent in Authorize.net to your website.

However, voiding and cancelling an order via Magento will send a "void transaction" to Authorize.net if you have the correct setup.